# Can i upload a scorm in moodle which out using all steps

Tags: moodle, scorm

Hi Team my question is in moodle to upload a scorm firstly we need to create a course >turn on editing >>then Adding a new SCORM package>> after this need o upload scorm file.

So i am thinking to make this process easier .but i am not sure which PHP function are being used in moodle at backend to upload scorm and create course automatically.

If any one knows please advise?

Comment: Any one with the solution please?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a course with a scorm activity, backup the course then restore it multiple times. But you will still need to edit and add the scorm package for each course.

There is also a command line tool called Moosh

https://moosh-online.com/

So you could create a course and add a scorm activity via the command line, but you will still need to edit and upload the scorm package for each course

Examples from https://moosh-online.com/commands/

```
moosh course-create --category 1 --fullname "full course name" --description "course description" --idnumber "course idnumber" shortname

moosh activity-add -n scorm1 -o '--intro=my intro ABC --forcenewattempt=1' scorm 2
```